# Change inode ctime in Linux

Tags: c, linux, timestamp

utimensat() updates ctime when restoring atime and/or mtime, but I need to restore all 3 timestamps. I solved this in a tricky way, by saving the current clock, moving system clock to the needed ctime, calling utimensat(), restoring current clock.
It does the job, but I understand this is a bad solution, so I'm looking for a better one, all in (root) userspace without kernel mods.
Here is the code I wrote to verify utimensat() behaviour and test the solution.

```
/* Test utimensat() behaviour, restore also Change timestamp
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MYFILE  "/home/user1/Work/myfile.txt"

static int get_timestamps(struct stat *sb, const char *descr) {

    sleep(1);

    if (stat(MYFILE, sb) == -1) {
        perror("stat(" MYFILE ") ERROR");
        return(errno);
    }

    char *a = ctime(&sb->st_atime);
    char *m = ctime(&sb->st_mtime);
    char *c = ctime(&sb->st_ctime);
    printf("%s\n", descr);
    printf("Last file access:       %.*s.%lu\n",    (int)strlen(a)-1, a, sb->st_atim.tv_nsec);
    printf("Last file modification: %.*s.%lu\n",    (int)strlen(m)-1, m, sb->st_mtim.tv_nsec);
    printf("Last status change:     %.*s.%lu\n\n",  (int)strlen(c)-1, c, sb->st_ctim.tv_nsec);

    return(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int rc = 0;
    struct stat sb_original;
    struct stat sb;

    // Get file stats
    rc = get_timestamps(&sb_original, "Initial");
    if (rc) return(rc);

    // Read file
    FILE *myfile = fopen(MYFILE, "r");
    if (myfile == NULL) {
        perror("fopen(" MYFILE ") ERROR");
        return(errno);
    }
    char buffer[10];
    (void)fread(buffer, 1, 1, myfile);
    (void)fclose(myfile);
    rc = get_timestamps(&sb, "After fopen(); fread(); fclose()");
    if (rc) return(rc);

    system("touch " MYFILE);
    rc = get_timestamps(&sb, "After touch");
    if (rc) return(rc);

    // Restore original Last Access timestamp updated after fopen(); fread(); fclose()
    if (sb.st_ino) {
        int have_sudo = 0;
        struct timespec ts[2], tsctime, tsnow;
        ts[0].tv_sec = sb_original.st_atim.tv_sec;
        ts[0].tv_nsec = sb_original.st_atim.tv_nsec;
        ts[1].tv_sec = sb_original.st_mtim.tv_sec;
        ts[1].tv_nsec = sb_original.st_mtim.tv_nsec;
        tsctime.tv_sec = sb_original.st_mtim.tv_sec;
        tsctime.tv_nsec = sb_original.st_mtim.tv_nsec;
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsnow) < 0) {
            perror("clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME) ERROR");
            return(errno);
        }
        /* ##### Fixme: is there a better way to restore all 3 timestamps? */
        // Bad solution but does the job ;)
        if (clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsctime) < 0) {
            perror("clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME,ctime) ERROR");
            if (errno != EPERM)
                return(errno);
            have_sudo = 1;
        }
        if (utimensat(0, MYFILE, ts, 0) < 0) {  // This updates Change timestamp!
            perror("utimensat(" MYFILE ") ERROR");
            return(errno);
        }
        if (have_sudo && clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsnow) < 0) {
            perror("clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME,now) ERROR");
            return(errno);
        }
        rc = get_timestamps(&sb, "After utimensat()");
        if (rc) return(rc);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please explcitly state what is **not** working. You probaly do this indireclty in your question, but err .. why so complicated?

Comment: There's no interface to change `ctime`. Without modifying the kernel, your solution is probably as close as you can get.

Comment: It looks like you can do it through `debugfs` too, but make sure the filesystem is unmounted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36024/103501

Comment: The kernel-only control of ctime was intentional.  Changing system time with settimeofday() & call utime();  or  debugfs (for unmounted extN filesystems) are about all of the simple ways to do this.  Changing system time is not a good idea - for example: it has the potential to alter what the cron daemon does.

Comment: @alk, many thanks to who simplified the title, english isn't my language.

Comment: @filipe-gonçalves, I'm developing a forensics examination tool, but in some cases I need to work with mounted filesystems.
I explored [http://bindfs.org/] but it seems not to solve my problem.
When working on an image, 'xmount --cache' may be simpler than 'debugfs', thanks to discardable cache.

Comment: @jim-mcnamara, I understand some ctime resilience to tampering is a good security measure, and its sabotage could have side effects.
Now I'm wondering if calling 'utimensat()' in a critical section could help to mitigate system time tampering side effects.